# Html opening multiple links on the page in a same new window

Tags: javascript, html

We have a html page which has approxi 10 links on it.

1. After clicking on the link, it should open a new browser window and display the text.
2. After the second click the application should display the relevant text in the already opened new browser window(the window openened in step 1 above).
3. This is then true for all further window clicks.

There should be only at the max two browser windows open on the user's computer.

I have tried with the following two ways and it did not work. The every click on the link has opened a new broswer window. That means after clicking all ten links I had 11 browser windows open. Here are the two basic ways which I have tried.

i)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="infoWindow">
    link1
</a>
```

ii)

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', 'infoWindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">info1</a>
```

Can somebody suggest a solution?

Comment: To be more precise, you want the browser to open link A in window A. If you click link A again, then it will focus on window A instead of creating a new window for the same link?

Comment: Do you have an example fiddle?

Comment: Not clearly able to understand what is your requirement.May be you can provide with a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are calling your window by the same name and yet they are still opening in a new window, it could be because your onclick function hasn't get specific scope to save the reference to the window.

If you were to change onclick to a function you can cache the window.

```
//js
var myWindow;
function myClick(){
    myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", "infoWindow", "width=300, height=250");
    return false;
}

//html
<a href="#" onclick="myClick()">info1</a>
```

Great article here : [infimum.dk](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html)